# How to remove email address from local database in mu4e?

Tags: mu4e

I use `mu4e` to read and write email. One email address that was in the LDAP server before no longer exists, but it still shows and auto-completes in `mu4e`.

How can I remove that address from the local database? And where is that database stored?

Comment: Does the answer in this issue https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1401 solve your problem? Maybe you could answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For mu version > 1.3.2. you need to define a filtering function and store its name in `mu4e-contact-process-function`, e.g. like in this example

```
(defun my-mu4e-contact-filter-function (addr)
  (if (string-match-p
        (concat "\\(?:no-?reply\\|.*\\.unwanted\\.domain\\.com\\|"
        "unwanted\\.user@somedomain\\.com\\)")
        addr)
     nil
  addr))
(setq mu4e-contact-process-function 'my-mu4e-contact-filter-function)
```

Note that the contact list only seems to get renewed when mu4e is started. So you will need to stop/restart mu4e upon changes.

Comment: I confirm that this works as of mu4e 1.14.13. I couldn't find how to stop and restart mu4e, so I restarted Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1401#issuecomment-499161051), one solution is to ignore that address in address completion. Add this code in `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq mu4e-compose-complete-ignore-address-regexp
      (concat "\\(?:no-?reply\\|.*\\.unwanted\\.domain\\.com\\|"
              "unwanted.email@domain\\.com\\)"))
```

and notice the escaping of periods with (`\\.`). Then restart `mu4e`.

The database of contacts will be stored in the Xapian database starting with `mu4e` 1.4.

Comment: Note for others finding this answer: `mu4e-compose-complete-ignore-address-regexp` has been obsoleted since mu 1.3.2. You need now to define the name of a filtering function in the variable `mu4e-contact-process-function`.

Comment: @dfeich Correct, could you write an answer with a reference and a code snippet?

Comment: This apparently worked for me with mu 1.8.3